# Unable to accept two dimensional String Array returned from a method

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, r.java-file

First of All :-) , I am not that proficient in java.

So in below code I am trying to print a two dimensional string returned from method. But unable to do it. Getting type mismatch error. can any one help.

```
public class ExcelUtilAdvanced {

    public String[][] getDatafromExcel(){
        
        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        String[][] data = new String[rowCount-1][colCount];
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<colCount;j++) {
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                data[i-1][j] = format.formatCellValue(cell);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data);
    return data;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int rowCount = 2;
        int colCount = 7;
        
        ExcelUtilAdvanced eua = new ExcelUtilAdvanced("fileName.xlsx", "sheetName");
        String[][] data = new String[rowCount][colCount];
        
        for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<colCount;j++) {
                data[i-1][j]= eua.getDatafromExcel(); //Type Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[][] to String
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `data[i-1][j]` is a `String`. `getDatafromExcel()` returns an array of `String` arrays. So it doesn't fit. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: wanted to store array returned by method in string array. As mentioned in answers , i was not receiving data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `String[][]` object into a `String` variable. I think you can declare and initialize directly the `String[][]` object passing the result returned by that method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rowCount = 2;
    int colCount = 7;

    ExcelUtilAdvanced eua = new ExcelUtilAdvanced("fileName.xlsx", "sheetName");
    String[][] data = eua.getDatafromExcel();
}
```

Edit: Also, you have to modify the rest of your code, so you'll able to handle `rowCount` and `colCount` variables (maybe you can put them in first method as input parameters), cause you aren't using those in `String[][]` declarations.

Like:

```
String[][] data = eua.getDatafromExcel(rowCount, colCount);
```

And you have to put `System.out.println` at the end of each loops, in order to print your `String[][]` while you assign values.
You can't print just your `data` variable.

General example:

```
for(int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
        System.out.print(data[i-1][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks pal. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new 2-D array to copy the stuff from  `getDatafromExcel():`

create a new 2-D array like this :

```
String[][] toFill =  new String[2][7];
```

or if you can use this :

```
String[][] data = new String[rowCount][colCount];
```

In code your main method should look like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int rowCount = 2;
int colCount = 7;

ExcelUtilAdvanced eua = new ExcelUtilAdvanced("fileName.xlsx", "sheetName");
String[][] data = new String[rowCount][colCount];
String[][] toFill =  new String[2][7];

for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<colCount;j++) {
        toFill= eua.getDatafromExcel(); 
    }

}
```

}

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int rowCount = 2;
int colCount = 7;

ExcelUtilAdvanced eua = new ExcelUtilAdvanced("fileName.xlsx", "sheetName");
String[][] data = new String[rowCount][colCount];
data= eua.getDatafromExcel();
```

}

Comment: If that's what OP was trying to do I think you can safely remove the loops (and the "Type mismatch" comment, for that matter).